# How to add a numbering before each start of row of json (formatted)

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]

Here is Stackblitz link:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqz1hr?file=src/app/app.component.html

I am trying to achieve:-

1) I am trying to add numbering before each json row  ( row number) as show in image.

2) Add different backgroundcolor ie #000 to the numbering column.

### .html

```
<div  class="col-12 rmpm" style="background:#292a30;height: 300px;">
 <pre id="responseSection" *ngIf="JSON" [innerHtml]="JSON"></pre>
</div>
```

### .ts

```
constructor(){
  let json = {'key':2 ,'key2':3}
 this.output(this.syntaxHighlight(JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 4)));
}

output(inp) {
        this.JSON = inp;
    }
  syntaxHighlight(json) {
        json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
            var cls = 'number';
            if (/^"/.test(match)) {
                if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                    cls = 'key';
                } else {
                    cls = 'string';
                }
            } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'boolean';
            } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'null';
            }
            return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance It's available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqz1hr?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Why munge up your data? You have two distinct datasets here. 1: line numbers, 2: JSON. They are unrelated as every line number will exist without regard in anyway to the JSON data. Therefore, the best way to solve this little conundrum is to use your grid system effectively. I see the `col-12` - make it `col-11` and give a column to the line numbers. Then populate them independently of one another. Your issue here is believing a line number must relate to a specific bit of JSON and that is not true here. Just a thought.

Comment: @Randy Casburn, Can you  please show your approach, so that styling of column containing serial no becomes easy.

Comment: Although you've already accepted an answer, I'll help out. First, your RegEx match function removes your HTML markup so you won't get any highlighting. You'll need to look into that. Since your `syntaxHighlight()` function does nothing, I've ignored that feature. So here is a stackblitz that cleans things up and uses bootstrap properly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mb5bdb If you have other questions for me, you are welcome to start a chat with me here or find me on LinkedIn

Comment: Thanks, but here serial no is not displaying correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to do another `.replace` at the end, using a callback function that retrieves and increments a `line` variable every time:

```
let line = 1;
// ...
return json.replace(...
// ...
.replace(/^/gm, () => line++ + '  ');
```

But with that, the spacing won't be proper between lines 9 and 10, and lines 99 and 100, and so on, so you might use `padEnd` instead:

```
const withHtml = json.replace( ...
// ...
const totalLines = withHtml.match(/\n/g).length;
const padLength = 5 + Math.floor(totalLines / 10);
return withHtml.replace(/^/gm, () => String(line++).padEnd(padLength));
```

To additionally color the line numbers, insert an HTML string instead, for example

```
return withHtml.replace(
  /^/gm,
  () => `<span class="line-number">${String(line++).padEnd(padLength)}</span>`
);
```

and style `.line-number` as desired.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't add backgroundColor to the numbering column by doing so as there is in image.

Comment: I am getting some issue. Can you please update this on my Stackblitz.

Comment: Just copy the text in the answer and style as desired, eg https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kspdah , there's probably a better CSS way of doing it though